# sql query don't show duplication records

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Customers
id,name,orderid
----------------------
1,Ted, 1
2,Jen, 2

Orders
id,prodname
----------------------
1,widgetA
1,widgetC
2,widgetB
2,widgetA


desired results
name, prodname
----------------------
Ted, widgetA
' ', widgetC
Jen, widgetB
' ', widgetA
```

Basically I don't want to repeat the customer's name if she has more than one product. Is there a way to do this?

**Solution:**

```
Select 
    (CASE WHEN myrow=1 THEN Name ELSE ' ' END) AS Name,
    product
From
(
    Select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Name ORDER BY c.Name) AS myrow,     
        o.productname AS product 
    FROM 
        Customers c JOIN 
        Orders o ON c.orderid = o.id 
) T1

Order By Name
```

Comment: You should definitely do this on the display layer not on a database level

Comment: @Lamak: but you might wanna do this if you are returning a result set to use within SQL Reporting Services report

Comment: I say use cursor but I feel too lazy to come up with a solution that uses cursor

Comment: @Sung - Reporting Services deal just fine with data like this (thats why tablix exists), and can display this in many different ways without repeating the name

Comment: I also wonder why the Customers table has an orderid.  Typically it would be the Orders table that has a customerid.  This would allow a customer to place more than one order.

Comment: sorry for bad table design, i was mainly after the concept and if it could be done or not. Looking back at it now, uhh!! that was pretty bad!

Comment: I should have used Orders and OrderDetails tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, though there is a strong case to use a different solution;  If you are using sql server take a look at "row_number()".  I don't use SQL Server, but it might look something like this:

```
Select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.Name) AS myrow,
    if(myrow=1,name,' ') AS name,
    o.productname AS product
FROM
    Customers c JOIN
    Orders o ON c.orderid = o.id
```

Comment: It's not TSQL compliant but I wish that such syntax could be allowed in TSQL.

Comment: You get a vote up just for introducing me to the row_number function (even if it shouldn't be used in this situation).

Comment: got it to work by making sql provided a sub-select and placed the if(cond,true,false) CASE statement in container sql.

Comment: @rod - you should show your solution in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is an ambiguity here.  What do you expect to happen if there are two Teds?

There is most likely a way to do this with SQL, though it may vary depending on what server you are running. I strongly advice against it, though.  You'd turn what is a simple and efficient query with a single join (assuming you have indexes set properly) into something overly complicated.

What you desire should really be done on the display / consumer side.  You'll undoubtedly get a solution, but I'd go with a standard join.  I'd also add the customer id to the output to avoid the aforementioned ambiguity.